# How to modify cache settings on a running ignite instance?

Tags: ignite

Is there any `setOrCreateCache` method in ignite? I just find a `getOrCreateCache` method.

I want to modify cache settings on a running ignite instance. How to?

My ignite version is `1.9.0`. Thanks.

Here is my codes:

```
IgniteCache<Integer, String> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCacheName");  // I've created a cache

// How to change the config of myCacheName?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create cache on running ignite by using [getOrCreateCache(CacheConfiguration cacheCfg)](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/1.9.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html#getOrCreateCache(org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration)) method. It's possible to dynamically configure cache before create it.

Comment: Thanks. But I find this method will not change the cache configuration. According to the doc: `If a cache with the same name already exist, this method will not check that the given configuration matches the configuration of existing cache and will return an instance of the existing cache.`

Comment: Yes, if cache already created, it will return instance of it. But if cache not created yet, new configuration will override configuration from xml.

Comment: Also, it's impossible to change configuration of already started cache

Comment: Thanks a lot.     :)